# How to normalize data when graphing the number of deaths of an epidemic

Tags: math, data-visualization

I have the following data for 1 country for covid-19 data:

```
{
  "count": 29,
  "result": [
    // removed for brevity
    {
      "confirmed": 6443,
      "date": "2020-04-04",
      "deaths": 373,
      "recovered": 205
    },
    {
      "confirmed": 6830,
      "date": "2020-04-05",
      "deaths": 401,
      "recovered": 205
    },
    {
      "confirmed": 7206,
      "date": "2020-04-06",
      "deaths": 477,
      "recovered": 205
    },
    {
      "confirmed": 7693,
      "date": "2020-04-07",
      "deaths": 591,
      "recovered": 205
    },
    {
      "confirmed": 8419,
      "date": "2020-04-08",
      "deaths": 687,
      "recovered": 205
    },
    {
      "confirmed": 9141,
      "date": "2020-04-09",
      "deaths": 793,
      "recovered": 205
    },
    {
      "confirmed": 9685,
      "date": "2020-04-10",
      "deaths": 870,
      "recovered": 381
    }
  ]
}
```

I am  plotting a graph for several countries

As each country has different populations, how would I normalise the data to plot a better graph to better compare the rates in different countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pick a number that will define your unit, e.g. 100,000.
2. Divide every number (except the dates) by the population size of the given country, and multiply with 100,000.
3. Now your unit is confirmed cases (or deaths or recovered persons) per 100,000 residents.